# Text in a ractangle box

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to display array of text in rectangle boxes like this.
[image]

but I got it like text displayed as entire row
[image]

below is the code snippet

```html
<span *ngFor="let mfal of mfals" class="review-span mfal">
  {{mfal}}
</span>
```

```css
.mfal {
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
  color: white;
}
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
 <span *ngFor="let mfal of mfals" class="review-span mfal">
    {{mfal}}</span>

.mfal {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Make sure your element has a display of inline-block or inline, add corresponding padding and margin.

Answer (score 1):

`display` attributes of elements might be set to `block` somewhere in your code.

```css
.mfal {
  display: block;
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="review-span mfal">WANAB</span>
<span class="review-span mfal">WANAB</span>
```

Try `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`.

```css
.mfal {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="review-span mfal">WANAB</span>
<span class="review-span mfal">WANAB</span>
```

Comment: if I use inline they are displayed adjusent to each other but there is no space between them. it looks like single word